# How to pass a variable to unicode/raw (ur"") conversion function

Tags: python, text, unicode

I have no problem performing the following function when taking the actual text:

```
In [7]: str = ur"FOO 20\N40%"

In [8]: str
Out[8]: u'FOO 20\\N40%'
```

But in the actual case the word `"FOO 20\N40%"` are stored in a variable `mystring`.
Whats the way to do that? I tried this but failed:

```
In [13]: mynewstr = ur(mystr)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-0379c497611f> in <module>()
----> 1 mynewstr = ur(mystr)

NameError: name 'ur' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the source string consists of only ASCII characters as your example does, it's easy:

```
mynewstr = unicode(mystr)
```

Otherwise you need to know the encoding of your original string bytes and use that to convert to unicode. E.g. if you know the source is UTF-8:

```
mynewstr = mystr.decode('utf-8')
```

E.g.

```
>>> print mystring
FOO 20\N40%
>>> unicode(mystring)
u'FOO 20\\N40%'
>>> mystring.decode('utf-8')
u'FOO 20\\N40%'
```